# Trading view strategy tester

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is there a way to disable strategy tester from opening up automatically after adding a strategy to chart?
Also the properties inputs from the settings, to make it only accessible from the strategy tester.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible I think, by default, a backtest strategy script always opens the strategy tester first. There is no way to change that
Maybe, create a ticket to the TradingView helpdesk team asking for this to change?